# Sum Linq query into one row

Tags: c#, oracle, linq

i need a way to combine a multi row linq query into one row and sum all the merged rows .eg

```
where alldates.years <= Now()
```

will return

```
 Col1   col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
1) 2015     2     1     0    0      4
2) 2014     3     0     1    1      5 
3) 2013     1     1     1    1      1
```

Needs to come out as

```
 col1  col2  clo3  col4  col5  col6
1) 2015   6     2      2     2    10
```

I need the grouping method to be specific.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You may have to improve the code formatting yourself. Also maybe flesh out the code you used?

Comment: which column in used for grouping ?

Comment: apologies i should have stated the grouping is for all rows that are returned so it is a sum of groupings that will return the highest date in the records provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code should produce the output, you are looking for. I have used test data in the Main method.

```
    public class Result
    {
        public DateTime col1 { get; set; }
        public int col2 { get; set; }
        public int col3 { get; set; }
        public int col4 { get; set; }
        public int col5 { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
        {
            List<Result> listTest = new List<Result>();
            listTest.Add(new Result() { col1 = DateTime.Now, col2 =1, col3 =3, col4 =5, col5=11});
            listTest.Add(new Result() { col1 = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1), col2 = 1, col3 = 3, col4 = 5, col5 = 11 });
            listTest.Add(new Result() { col1 = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1), col2 = 1, col3 = 3, col4 = 5, col5 = 11 });

            var maxYearLessThanCurrentYear = listTest.Where(x => x.col1.Year < DateTime.Now.Year).Select(x => x.col1.Year).Max();

            var output = listTest.Where(x => x.col1.Year < DateTime.Now.Year)
                               .Select( x => new  { x.col2, x.col3, x.col4, x.col5, maxYearLessThanCurrentYear })
                               .GroupBy(x=>x.maxYearLessThanCurrentYear)
                               .Select(x => new Result
                               {
                                   col1 = new DateTime(x.Key, 1, 1) ,
                                   col2 = x.Sum(y => y.col2),
                                   col3 = x.Sum(y => y.col3),
                                   col4 = x.Sum(y => y.col4),
                                   col5 = x.Sum(y => y.col5),
                               })
                               .FirstOrDefault();
     }
```